Docusaurus: Is it possible to exclude (hide) a file when using mdx DocCardList, while displaying the rest?
[some edits to clarify]
I'm using
import DocCardList from '@theme/DocCardList';

<DocCardList />

This is to get the "boxes" that go to other pages on the "main" page. I'd like to exclude (or hide) one of the files from displaying, where everything else displays. Is it possible?
The goal is to do this twice, where I get two boxes, more text, and then the other two boxes.
With regard to what I've tried: I don't even know what to try; things like exclude and hide  didn't work. I've searched for help but I'm probably not using the right search words.
(OK, I got a few suggestions via tags, but those weren't helpful for my situation, unfortunately.)

If you want to have a .mdx file in your docs directory, but you don't wan it to display on your Docusaurus site, you can prepend your .mdx files with a _.
For example, in the following file structure, _.File-4.mdx will not create a doc page on your Docusaurus site.
docs folder/
├── File-1.mdx
├── File-2.mdx
├── File-3.mdx
└── _File-4.mdx

This way, you can keep that docs file in your site directory, but keep it "unpublished."

Hmm, this will be useful at some point (so thanks) but it wasn't what I was looking for.
I was looking for ways to tweak using DocCardList so that it publishes some of the files on the page (the files in the boxes) but not all of them.
